# How to know file .apk use to the keystore to sign?

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, signature, keystore

I have a keystore and a apk. is there a tool or a method to check file apk, signed from this keystore? I use Eclipse.
Someome help me please.
Thanks so much

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use jarsigner tool:

```
jarsigner -verify -verbose -keystore keystore_file apk_file.apk
```

This command gives output like this:

> smk    22401 Tue Aug 30 10:20:52 SAMST 2011 res/drawable/about_cover.png
>   smk     1206 Tue Aug 30 10:20:52 SAMST 2011 res/drawable/add_normal.png
>   smk     1430 Tue Aug 30 10:20:52 SAMST 2011 res/drawable/app_icon.png
>   smk      133 Tue Aug 30 10:20:52 SAMST 2011 res/drawable/background_next_section.png
>
> s = signature was verified
>     m = entry is listed in manifest
>     k = at least one certificate was found in keystore

Comment: Hi Sergey Thanks for reply,
How is difference between "apk don't sign from this keystore" and "apk don't sign from this keystore"? In the parameters s, m, k: do u use k only?

Comment: I tried to do this command. With keystore that .apk signed, ouput:  smk 47100 Wed Aug 31 15:13:38 ICT 2011 classes.dex.  
On the other hand, ouput:   sm 47100 Wed Aug 31 15:13:38 ICT 2011 classes.dex

Comment: Yes, I use only "k". If APK was signed with certificate from given keystore, then it will be "k" in output.