# Using jarsigner -verify on an APK asks me to specify an alias?

Tags: java, android, jarsigner

I'm trying to check the signature information on an APK. The [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html) say to use

```
jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs app.apk
```

and [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104624/how-to-check-the-android-apk-is-signed-or-unsigned) SO [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268828/how-to-know-file-apk-use-to-the-keystore-to-sign) agree. But if I grab JDK 1.7 and do that, I get the error:

```
Please specify alias name
```

Which is hard to work with, considering that [googling](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=jarsigner+%22Please+specify+alias+name%22&oq=jarsigner+%22Please+specify+alias+name%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=3089247l3098661l0l3098947l39l30l1l0l0l0l1032l7178l1.19.3.4.1.1.0.1l31l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=7ab4fd5491c5b229&biw=1328&bih=738) the error message returns nothing but links to the jarsigner source.

What's going on?

Comment: if you use an ide like eclispse its far more easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alias should only be required if you are signing an APK. What version of the JDK are you using? Is it the Sun/Oracle JDK?

BTW, you shouldn't use Java 7 for android development, it is not officially supported. Also note that the jarsigner default digest algorithm has been changed, so signing with Java 6 and Java 7 will produce different results if you don't explicitly specify the digest algorithm.

Comment: I was using JDK1.7.0_01, I'm trying 1.6 now. (I'm not a Java guy, I just grabbed what appeared to be the recommended release from Sun.)

Answer (score 2):

I found the same error could be happening if the alias contains spaces:

```
ALIAS WITH SPACES
```

I managed to overcome this by specifying the alias with quotes. This works even within properties of Maven files:

```
'ALIAS WITH SPACES'
```

Answer (score 1):

use:
 **$ jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs app.apk**

on **app > build > ouputs > apk** path

if you see CN phrase then your .apk is "debug",

else congrats! you signed your .apk, its "release" now.